# How to create a stored procedure to set a default value for a specific column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table "State" In which I already had some columns and data. Now I altered the table and added a new column of type int. Now I wanted to set that column value default for all existing records.My new column is "Default" of type int. I want to set the Default value as 3 for all existing records. Wanted to do it by using a stored procedure.
can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE State
SET [Default]=3
WHERE [Default] IS NULL
```

To Create Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SetDefaultValue
(@TableName varchar(30),
 @ColName varchar(30),
 @DefValue int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query as varchar(300)
    SET @Query='UPDATE '+@TableName+' SET ['+@ColName+'] = '+@DefValue
    EXEC(@Query)
END
```